# How to add/insert a class to a sidebar in single.php?

Tags: css

I have a sidebar displaying in the home and single pages. When it shows up in the home page, it has an already defined css class (width:30%)

When it shows up in the single page, i want to add/insert a new class to that sidebar. I want this new style to modify the predifined elements.So it ends with a width of 35%

I tried to do it as follows:

**In functions.php (child theme)**

```
function sidebar_class() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $class = 'sidebar-single';
    }
    return $class;
}
```

**In sidebar.php**

```
<div id="secondary" class="sidebar1-area <?php sidebar_class(); ?>" role="complementary">
```

**The html result should be:**

```
<div id="secondary" class="sidebar1-area sidebar-single" role="complementary">
```

**Original css values for the class**

```
width: 30%
```

**Final result**

```
width:35%
```

How can I accomplish this in the most efficient way?

Comment: Well does it not work in the way you did it? Also if your theme uses `body_class()` properly you could just style `.single #secondary`

Comment: Hi Rarst, it is not working the way I did it. I am using the twentytwelve theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I accomplish this in the most efficient way?

As [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) indicates, don't change the class to change the style. Leave the class the same and use [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to change the style on certain pages.

When WordPress creates a page in a theme that uses the [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function it adds a lot of information about the page in the html class of the body tag. Look at that tag on a page created by single.php and that class will include the class name *single*.

Use that to specify the style for single.php files.

```
#secondary {
    /** These styles work on all pages. */
}

body.single #secondary {
    /** These styles only work on single.php pages. */
}

body.home #secondary {
    /** These styles only work on home pages. */
}
```

See the [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function for details on which classes are added.

Comment: Thats awesome! It worked just the way I wanted. I am still learning my CSS. Thanks to you and Rarst.

Comment: By the way, could anyone tell me why the way I was trying to do it didnt work?

Comment: You didn't `echo` `sidebar_class()` in the PHP call. You just called the function and threw the return value away.